# wp post_tag change minlength

Tags: javascript, jquery, wp-admin

I try to change minlength value from post tag search in wp-admin

```
(wp-admin/js/tags-suggest.js) -> .fn.wpTagsSuggest -> options -> minLength
```

but  cant override this value

Comment: why do you want to change this?

Comment: because  i have 5000+ tags, and if put 2 letters, I cant get list of hundreds tags, redis doesnt help a lot

Comment: the options array can be used to override this, but without knowing where in WP Admin and which specific interface that may be difficult to answer. It's also possible the UI you're referring to does not use that library, I can't be sure

Comment: And how it can be overrided? It's for normal post tag search by adding new article, defualt by wp

Comment: if I knew how I would have written an answer/solution below, these are just the comments, they're intended to ask clarifying questions, clear up misunderstandings, or enquire about additional context. As for the default tag search, do you mean the classic post editor, the block editor, a page builder? The default can mean different things in different contexts, e.g. the default post tag interface is not the same depending on settings and plugins. E.g. the default post block editor does not use `wpTagsSuggest`